# How to properly set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX from the command-line

Tags: installation, cmake

I want to generate a Makefile with an `install` target, making installation to `/usr` instead of default `/usr/local`. Assuming that the build directory is a subdirectory of the source directory, I execute:

```bash
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr ..
```

CMakeCache.txt contains: `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr` (OK?)

Now I execute:

```bash
make
make install
```

All files are still installed to `usr/local`. What is wrong?

Edit: There is no `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in any of the CMakeLists.txt project files.
Before running cmake, I delete everything from the output directory.
install directives in CMakeLists.txt look like:

```
install(TARGETS mylibrary DESTINATION lib)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on CMake v3.24.2 and Make v4.3 (the latest versions at the time of this comment). Can you try to reproduce it with the tools you are using now? Do you remember what versions of CMake and Make you were using when you wrote the question?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

That should be (see the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html)):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```

Comment: Just to save people some time: Use single 'quote' NOT "double" when passing strings with possible spaces.  The double results in CMake creating folders named ; from the source.  It will do so without erroring.

Answer (score 44):

There are two ways to use this variable:

- passing it as a command line argument just like Job mentioned:

  `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=< install_path > ..`
- assigning value to it in `CMakeLists.txt`:

  `SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX < install_path >)`

  But **do remember to place it BEFORE** `PROJECT(< project_name>)` command, otherwise it will not work!

Comment: Strange, the SET() statement works for me only if I place it AFTER the PROJECT() statement (CMake 2.8).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39485990/1938798) and the reference it links to more directly discusses the before/after the project() command issue.

Comment: What is this `PROJECT` command and how to have this `cmake` option before it ? You would have an example ?

Comment: `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/usr" CACHE STRING " " FORCE )` , it's ok even if place it after `project(<project_name>)`.

Answer (score 12):

> But do remember to place it BEFORE PROJECT(< project_name>) command,
>   otherwise it will not work!

My first week of using cmake - after some years of GNU autotools - so I am still learning (better then writing m4 macros), but I think modifying CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX **after** setting project is the better place.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /foo/bar/bubba)
message("CIP = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} (should be /foo/bar/bubba")
project (BarkBark)
message("CIP = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} (should be /foo/bar/bubba")
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /foo/bar/bubba)
message("CIP = ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} (should be /foo/bar/bubba")
```

First run (no cache)

```
CIP = /foo/bar/bubba (should be /foo/bar/bubba
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7
-- etc, etc,...
CIP = /usr/local (should be /foo/bar/bubba
CIP = /foo/bar/bubba (should be /foo/bar/bubba
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Second run

```
CIP = /foo/bar/bubba (should be /foo/bar/bubba
CIP = /foo/bar/bubba (should be /foo/bar/bubba
CIP = /foo/bar/bubba (should be /foo/bar/bubba
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Let me know if I am mistaken, I have a lot of learning to do. It's fun.

Comment: Try to use FORCE when you do SET:  set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /foo/bar/bubba CACHE PATH "Cmake prefix" FORCE)

Answer (score 4):

In modern CMake CLI, it's even easier. The last command installs the targets in `build` folder to `myInstallationDirectory` using the `prefix` option.

```
cmake -S . -B build
cmake --build build
cmake --install build --prefix myInstallationDirectory
```

Reference: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html?highlight=install#cmdoption-cmake--install-0

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

Place this code to the cmakelist.txt at the very top:

```
SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX < install_path >)
```

For some reason, doing it via the command line does not work for me:

```
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/user/Human-Detection-Module/build/install/
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, to add exteranl projects:

The following works for me (cmake for windows: v3.25.2) based on [this thread](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-December/041135.html):

```
project("My_Project" VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

if(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
    
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external 
        CACHE PATH "Force path to set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX" FORCE)

endif(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
```

To verify, run `$> ccmake build` or `$> ccmake .` in the build directory to see the cache variable set to:

```bash
 CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                 Debug                                                                                     
 CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES        Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo                                                   
 CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS    ON                                                                                        
 CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX             D:/Projects/CMakeTest/external
```

Previously it was:

```bash
 CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE                 Debug                                                                                     
 CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES        Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo                                                   
 CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS    ON                                                                                        
 CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX             C:/Program Files/My_Project
```

This is on windows, I reckon that it would be `/usr/cmake/My_project` on linux.(if someone could confirm)

**EDIT:**

If the changes do not reflect, you can delete the `CMakeCache.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I used export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH= <path> and that worked fine for me.

Comment: Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22215900/add-the-installation-prefix-of-qt5widgets-to-cmake-prefix-path