# How does project(...) affect variables?

Tags: cmake

I stumbled upon the following nice cmake feature recently:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT.html

Save the following snippet as CMakeLists.txt, run `mkdir build; cd build`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

message(STATUS "CMID: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT}")

project( test )
```

Executing that snippet does *not* output a true variable:

```
➜  build /usr/bin/rm -rf *; cmake ../ | grep CMID
-- CMID:
```

Now if you change that snippet:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project( test )

message(STATUS "CMID: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT}")
```

Execution yields the result, I expect from the documentation:

```
➜  build /usr/bin/rm -rf *; cmake ../ | grep CMID
-- CMID: 1
```

So I wonder, how does the relative position of the `project( ... )` command change that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project()` call sets many CMake variables, and *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT* is one of such variables.

So, for many CMake commands and variables' accesses placing them before or after the `project()` call is crusial.

In most cases, `project()` call should be **before** the using of the other commands and variables.

---

If you are looking for a way of changing default install prefix from the `CMakeLists.txt`, see that my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485990/3440745.