# CMake GTest fatal error (missing stdlib.h) when cross compiling

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, googletest

## Set-up

I have the following files.

### empty.cc:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

### CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_MINIMUM_VERSION 3.8)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ${CMAKE_MINIMUM_VERSION})

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

set(gtest_test gtest-test)
add_executable(${gtest_test} empty.cc)
#target_link_libraries(${gtest_test} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES}) # Line A
target_link_libraries(${gtest_test} GTest::GTest GTest::Main) # Line B
```

### toolchain.cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 4.14.0)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)


set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/zynq/xtl/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/zynq/xtl/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-g++)

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE NEVER)


set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf)
```

## Problem

I build it using:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain.cmake .. && make VERBOSE=1 -j
```

When I link against `GTest` using `Line A`, i.e., `target_link_libraries(${gtest_test} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES})`, then everything is OK. But when I use `Line B`, i.e., `target_link_libraries(${gtest_test} GTest::GTest GTest::Main)`, then I've got the following error:

```
/opt/zynq/xtl/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-g++ --sysroot=/opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf   -isystem /opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf/include   -o CMakeFiles/gtest-test.dir/empty.cc.o -c /home/xxx/git/cmake/cmake-with-gtest/empty.cc
In file included from /home/xxx/git/cmake/cmake-with-gtest/empty.cc:1:
/opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf/include/c++/8.3.0/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
               ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/gtest-test.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 
'CMakeFiles/gtest-test.dir/empty.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gtest-test.dir/empty.cc.o] Error 1
```

`g++` version

```
...$ /opt/zynq/xtl/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-g++ --version
arm-linux-musleabihf-g++ (GCC) 8.3.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Normal build, i.e., not cross compiling, works fine using either

```
target_link_libraries(${gtest_test} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES}) # Line A
```

or

```
target_link_libraries(${gtest_test} GTest::GTest GTest::Main) # Line B
```

## Question

Why is it that using one way of linking results in a missing header and the other works just fine?

Comment: Small notes (unrelated to the problem): 1. A directory set in the `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable is **automatically** treated as one in the `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` list; no needs to explicitely add sysroot to `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` list. 2. Setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` generally is not part of the toolchain. See also pattern for setting default install prefix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481958/setting-cmake-install-prefix-from-cmakelists-txt-file.

Answer (score 2):

It is known that using `-isystem` for standard compiler include directories breaks `#include_next` directive which is widely used for standard C++ header files. See e.g. this question: [-isystem on a system include directory causes errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218953/isystem-on-a-system-include-directory-causes-errors).

CMake has a mechanism for filtering out standard compiler include directories, which uses variable [CMAKE_<LANG>_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_LANG_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html) as a list of include directories which are needed to be filtered out. Unfortunately, this list is not autodetected with a compiler (see that closed bugreport: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16291). Instead, directory `/usr/include` (relative to sysroot) is just added to that list.

Because in your toolchain compiler include directory is not a `/usr/include` but `/include` one, you need to add this directory to the exception list explicitely:

```
# in toolchain.cmake
list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/include)
# Setting the exclude directory for C compiler is optional:
# C standard headers rarely use `#include_next` directive
list(APPEND CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/include)
```

---

Difference between

```
target_link_libraries(${gtest_test} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} ${GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARIES}) # Line A
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(${gtest_test} GTest::GTest GTest::Main) # Line B
```

is that the `Line B` uses **targets names** for link with, and include directories assosiated with that targets are automatically added to the your executable. That is why you got `-isystem`.

The second way  (`Line B`) is treated as "modern" one and is suggested to be used in newly written code. But both methods should work.

Comment: Well... It doesn't work. I didn't mention, but I have `usr` in `/opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf` pointing to this directory, i.e., `usr -> .`. So `/opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf/include` if effectively the same as `/opt/zynq/xtl/arm-linux-musleabihf/usr/include`.