# How can I change the default CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using the line:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/INSTALL" CACHE PATH "Directory for sbnw installation")
```

as described in the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html) to change the default install directory from `C:/Program Files (x86)/SBNW` to `project_root/INSTALL`. However, I still want users to still be able to choose the default install path. After using this command, the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is still `C:/Program Files (x86)/SBNW`. Does anybody know why?

Comment: Where do you inserted this line into your `CMakeLists.txt`? It need to be set before the `project` command.

Comment: Yep, this did the trick. Presumably then, the CMAKE* variables all need to be set before project? If you make this coment an answer I'll accept.

Comment: There are already a few questions about this topic on the site, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20962671/3987854) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485990/3987854) answer, which appear to be most relevant to your situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting CMAKE\_INSTALL\_PREFIX from CMakeLists.txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481958/setting-cmake-install-prefix-from-cmakelists-txt-file)

Comment: Thanks @squareskittles. Just marked it as a duplicate.