# why doesnt cmake install prefix get set

Tags: dll, cmake, cmakelists-options

I am compiling a project. During the project i get the error `setlocal  if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd` i researched the error and it seems the error is related to read-write rights. I learned that it could be fixed using `cmake_install_prefix` value or by disabling UAC. I disabled UAC and made the `program files (x86)`'s owner my user. The problem didnt get fixed. Later than I tried to change the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` but i probably failed setting a value to it. After i initialize cmake, `cmakeCache.txt` shows that the path is still in program files

```
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files/xmrig
```

I use this code before project name

```
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/memoryModule/xmrig-master/xmrigReal" FORCE)
```

also i tried this

```
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/memoryModule/xmrig-master/xmrigReal" FORCE)
```

i still get the path as program files and i get the setlocal error. what could be the reason?
I also use `-DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE` if i dont use it there is no error but i need this.

if i put `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/memoryModule/path/xm"` it returns the error from the cli

```
The source directory "C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/memoryModule/path/xm/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/memoryModule/path/xm" does not exist
```

please help me compile it

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481958/setting-cmake-install-prefix-from-cmakelists-txt-file) about setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable in `CMakeLists.txt`? All your 3 attempts to set the variable are wrong...

Comment: do i use `SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "C:/withQuotes" CACHE PATH "this")`

like this then, seems like the install path is till `program files` @Tsyvarev

Comment: So, you attempt to use "not recommended" approach from my answer. Why? There is a correct approach at the top of the answer.

Comment: seems it worked, from the cmakecache, the install prefix is different, i still get error i'll look deep into it @Tsyvarev

Comment: this tread https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/xmrig-runtime-dll-crash @Tsyvarev if i remove `-DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE` it compiles but runtime error