# cmake and make does not create the folder and copy files into it

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, cmake

I use cmake and make to build some libs in Linux.
The install part of the CMakelist is given below:

```
add_library(RVO ${RVO_HEADERS} ${RVO_SOURCES})

if(WIN32)
    set_target_properties(RVO PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS NOMINMAX)
endif()

install(FILES ${RVO_HEADERS} DESTINATION include)
install(TARGETS RVO DESTINATION lib)
```

But when I run make, the lib is correctly built, but not moved to the corresponding foler "/lib" as expected, nor the "/include" folder is created with files copied in.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use CMAKE\_INSTALL\_PREFIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241922/how-to-use-cmake-install-prefix)

Comment: By default `make` runs `all` target. And `install` target isn't within its dependencies. So, run `make install`.

Comment: @arrowd That should be an answer.

Comment: I have tried, but now it gives an error says file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/home/shupeng/Documents/trajectorygenerationtoolbox/RVO2/src/RVO.h" to
  "/usr/local/include/RVO.h".
I do not want to create the include folder under /usr/bin, but rather locally.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to change where files are **installed** (relative to `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`), you use `DESTINATION` keyword in `install()` command call. To perform an installation, use need to run `make install`, because running just `make` will only **build** the project.

To alter locations where **built** binaries are placed (within building tree), you need to set [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html#prop_tgt:LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) property on `RVO` target. You can also set its default value with [CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html).