# How to uninstall libc++ after installing from source?

Tags: linux, llvm, uninstallation, llvm-clang, libc++

I installed libc++ from source using following script. The `make uninstall` is not supported. What would be the best way to uninstall it?

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm.git llvm-source
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx.git llvm-source/projects/libcxx
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxxabi.git llvm-source/projects/libcxxabi

export C_COMPILER=clang
export COMPILER=clang++

# Build and install libc++ 
mkdir llvm-build && cd llvm-build
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${C_COMPILER} -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${COMPILER} \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
      ../llvm-source
make cxx
sudo make install-cxxabi install-cxx
```

Comment: what does `make -n install-cxxabi install-cxx` shows?

Comment: Related: [what's the opposite of make install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439950/whats-the-opposite-of-make-install-i-e-how-do-you-uninstall-a-library-in-li). I recommend `checkinstall`, which will monitor what gets installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after lot of searching, it is clear that there is no automatic or even semi-automatic way to uninstall when `make unintsall` is not implemented. There are two ways to get around this:

1. If using cmake then run the install again but set the flag like `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=./output`. This will cause cmake to put all files in ./output. Now you can observe the files, and manually delete them. I think by default cmake would put these files at `/usr/local`.
2. Another [cool trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242041/207661) you can use if install_manifest.txt file is generated: `cat install_manifest.txt | xargs echo sudo rm | sh`.