# log4cplus file cannot create directory administrative privileges

Tags: cmake, log4cplus

I am trying to install Log4Cplus using Cmake.

First I downloaded log4cplus into a directory called `3rdparty`

```
git clone https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus.git --recursive
```

Later in the common CMakeLists.txt I did the following

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.4)
enable_testing()
include(USR_macros_and_functions.cmake)

project (unixpackages)
USR_init_project(unixpackages)
#other packages ...
add_subdirectory(3rdParty/log4cplus)
 #other packages ...
USR_add_build_repo_targets()
```

---

The problem is that when I try build I get the following error:

```
-- Installing: /home/compilation/UnixPackagesFareShopping/Output_API/Lib/libvalidator.so
-- Removed runtime path from "/home/compilation/UnixPackagesFareShopping/Output_API/Lib/libvalidator.so"
CMake Error at 3rdParty/log4cplus/src/cmake_install.cmake:36 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/log4cplus.  Maybe need
  administrative privileges.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  3rdParty/log4cplus/cmake_install.cmake:37 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:48 (include)
```

---

I understand that I don't have the right to install it into `/usr/local/lib64/cmake/` but the problem is that i don't know where I should change the path to point it to a directory where I have the rights to install it into.

I tried looking to see if i can find lib64 in all the configue and cmake files I only found this

```
./configure:  # 'ldconfig -N -X -v | grep ^/' on 64bit Fedora does not report /usr/lib64,
./configure:  # 'ldconfig -N -X -v | grep ^/' on 64bit Fedora does not report /usr/lib64,
./m4/libtool.m4:  # 'ldconfig -N -X -v | grep ^/' on 64bit Fedora does not report /usr/lib64,
```

I am new to cmake so sorry for the question

Comment: Do you mean during installation? Can you set the [CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) while configuration to a location where you have write privileges and try again?

Comment: I added SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdparty/log4cplus) in the CMakeLists.txt file of log4cplus but didn't work.

I also found something like ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/httpd but I don't know iwhere should place it. 

I don't want to add anything in the command line

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` affects on a **whole project**, including the subprojects. (That is, you cannot install your files under `/usr/local`, but files related to log4cplus into non-system location). See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241922/how-to-use-cmake-install-prefix) about proper setting `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable. (Referenced question has answers both for command line and for `CMakeLists.txt` file's modifications.)

Comment: Annnd it workeddd Thank you @Tsyvarev i did the following:

set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdParty/log4cplusclea CACHE PATH "Cmake prefix" FORCE)

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you can adjust the installation location using CMake, just use the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable (see answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6241922/3987854)). You can set this variable to somewhere you have access to, so the software is eventually installed in that location instead.

You can set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable on the command line when calling `cmake`, or in the CMake file itself *before* any calls to `project`, as you have done:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/3rdParty/log4cplusclea)
```