# How to specify install directory for shared libraries for jsoncpp 0.10.7 with cmake?

Tags: linux, cmake, c++03, jsoncpp

I'm building https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/tree/0.10.7 for an embedded system because that's the recommended version if c++03 support is still needed. My target is based on Ubuntu 12.04.

CMakeLists.txt has include(GNUInstallDirs) so I'm trying to specify the installation directories with

```
 cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=lib
```

I've tried various combinations of these and permutations, but cmake insists on installing the shared library in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu while I need it to be in /usr/lib.

I've followed the advice here: [How to use CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241922/how-to-use-cmake-install-prefix) but to no avail.

Oddly the INCLUDEDIR variable does put the include files where I want them.

Is there any way of getting the library where I want it without modifying CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 1):

While the project includes `GNUInstallDirs` module, it uses the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` (defined in this module) [only for pkg-config file install location](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/0.10.7/CMakeLists.txt#L121).

For libraries the project [introduces](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/0.10.7/CMakeLists.txt#L33) `LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR` variable, and for header files - `INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR`.

So you need to set these variables, not the ones defined by `GNUInstallDirs` module.

Comment: That makes sense, and when I tried it, the correct values were set in CMakeCache.txt, but bizarrely it still does 
"Installing: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjsoncpp.so.0" etc

Comment: [The line](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/0.10.7/src/lib_json/CMakeLists.txt#L51) which determines final installation path contains `"${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}"`. According to the description of [CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE.html), it is set by CMake when it detects the system. I am not sure that it is intended to be redefined by the user (`-D` option for `cmake`), but you may try. Alternatively, you may try to edit the project's code.

Comment: That variable can't be redefined by the user. Thanks for pointing me at the relevant bit of code.