# Install Cmake occurs and error in Centos7. How to deal with it?

Tags: linux, cmake, centos

I need to install a software that needs cmake. Every step till make install work fine. Then at make install this is the error:

```
CMake Error at Source/kwsys/cmake_install.cmake:46 (file):
  file cannot create directory: /usr/local/doc/cmake-3.18/cmsys.  Maybe need
  administrative privileges.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:47 (include)

make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I don't have administrative privileges, so i can't just add sudo.
I am new to working with this, so please be a little bit easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

When running `cmake`, you can tell CMake to install the software in some other location that you have access to. Just set the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable to point to that location. So, your `cmake` command line might change from:

```
cmake ..
```

to this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/username/software/ ..
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20962671/3987854) response for another way to do this in the CMake file itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the good old `DESTDIR` (ed work, at least, with Makefile generator, and don't need to reconfigure).
ref: https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html

```sh
cmake --build build --target install -- DESTDIR=/home/username/software/
```

which should install in `/home/username/software/usr/local/[bin|lib|include]/...`