# How to install CMAKE

Tags: installation, cmake, debian

I'm new in Linux and I trying to install CMAKE but I get on this error . How can fix that:

> dania@dania:~/sz/lin/build$ cmake .. -D
> CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=[INSTALL_DIR] CMake Error: The source
> directory
> "/home/dania/sz/lin/build/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=[INSTALL_DIR]"
> does not exist. Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on
> the CMake GUI.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241922/how-to-use-cmake-install-prefix
(and i cannot make a comment)

Comment: Where I should put CMakeLists.txt ? in side ~/sz/lin/build  ?                                                                because when I run  cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..                                                                                                                          I get :                                                                                                                        CMake Error: The source directory "/home/dania/sz/lin" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Comment: Why do you specify `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=[INSTALL_DIR]` and where did you pick this up? You are probably reading an instruction about how to build `cmake` from source, which you don't need to do at all if you have already installed it with `apt-get`. (And if you do want to do that, `[INSTALL_DIR]` should be replaced with the actual installation directory.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install cmake cross-platform, open-source make system in all currently supported versions of Debian open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```