# DESTDIR and PREFIX of make

Tags: c, linux, bash, makefile, configure

I am trying to make software install to a specific directory. I found several ways, but not sure what are the differences between them.

1. `./configure --prefix=***`
2. `make install DESTDIR=***`
3. `make install prefix=***`

I am confused about the functions of these three. Do they achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

> `./configure --prefix=***`

**Number 1** determines where the package will go when it is installed, and where it will look for its associated files when it is run. It's what you should use if you're just compiling something for use on a single host.

---

> `make install DESTDIR=***`

**Number 2** is for installing to a temporary directory which is not where the package will be run from. For example this is used when building `deb` packages. The person building the package doesn't actually install everything into its final place on his own system. He may have a different version installed already and not want to disturb it, or he may not even be root. So he uses

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

so the program will expect to be installed in `/usr` when it runs, then

```
make install DESTDIR=debian/tmp
```

to actually create the directory structure.

---

> `make install prefix=***`

**Number 3** is going to install it to a different place but not create all the directories as `DESTDIR=/foo/bar/baz` would. It's commonly used with GNU stow via

```plaintext
./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && sudo make install prefix=/usr/local/stow/foo
```

, which would install binaries in `/usr/local/stow/foo/bin`. By comparison,

```plaintext
make install DESTDIR=/usr/local/stow/foo
```

would install binaries in `/usr/local/stow/foo/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: For what it's worth, in a cmake-based build you can emulate "case 4" (for stow, etc) by running `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/foo/bar/baz -P cmake_install.cmake` in the build directory.

Comment: @JackKelly: Thanks! I've been using DESTDIR with GNU stow and have had to fix-up the directory structure with a `mv usr/local/* . && rmdir usr/local && rmdir usr` typically -- using `prefix=` is much better!

Comment: Note: some software doesn't support `DESTDIR=/tmp/foo make install` ; for cmake based projects, I had more luck with `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/test1 -P cmake_install.cmake` which installs to  `/tmp/foo/{bin,...}` ; see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11833#issuecomment-401164056 for an example.

Comment: One more note: `DESTDIR` and `prefix` can be used on `make install` together, i.e. `make install DESTDIR=/foo/bar/tmp perfix=/local`.

Comment: So if I run `./configure --prefix=path1` and then `make install prefix=path2`, `path2` overrides `path1`, right? Is there any other differences between `path1` and `path2`?

Answer (score 3):

This can help illustrating the use of `DESTDIR` and `--prefix` (from [here](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html)):

> **Multiple installs using --prefix and DESTDIR:**
>
> Sepcify a different --prefix location/option for each build - at configure time. For eg:
>
> ```
> untar petsc tar ball
> ./configure --prefix=/opt/petsc/petsc-3.9.0-mpich --with-mpi-dir=/opt/mpich
> make
> make install DESTDIR=/tmp/petsc-pkg
> untar petsc tar ball
> ./configure --prefix=/opt/petsc/petsc-3.9.0-openmpi --with-mpi-dir=/opt/openmpi
> make
> make install DESTDIR=/tmp/petsc-pkg
> ```

Comment: In case the ./configure file is not provided, one can still install to user-specific directory using: make prefix=/path/to/your/lib/libaio install

Answer (score 0):

From `openssl/INSTALL`

> Package builders who want to configure the library for standard
>   locations, but have the package installed somewhere else so that
>   it can easily be packaged, can use
>
> ```
> $ make INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/package-root install
> ```
>
> (or specify "--install_prefix=/tmp/package-root" as a configure
>   option).  The specified prefix will be prepended to all
>   installation target filenames.

This is non-standard but INSTALL_PREFIX is used in some other programs.

This works for OpenSSL versions before 1.1.x. OpenSSL 1.1.x and later are able to recognize usual `DESTDIR`.