# Cmake is installing something to /usr/local/include and /usr/lib instead of /usr/include

Tags: cmake, glfw

i was reading this [How to build & install GLFW 3 and use it in a Linux project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768008/how-to-build-install-glfw-3-and-use-it-in-a-linux-project) because i was having trouble installing glfw. when i ran "make install" this was the output.

```
blah blah blah build target [100%]
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/GLFW
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/GLFW/glfw3.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/GLFW/glfw3native.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Config.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3ConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3/glfw3Targets-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/glfw3.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a
```

how do i install it in /usr/include instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr . && make all install
```

duplicate of [What is cmake equivalent of 'configure --prefix=DIR && make all install '?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003374/what-is-cmake-equivalent-of-configure-prefix-dir-make-all-install)

Comment: That doesn't work for /usr/lib instead of /usr/local/lib, does it?