# How do you fix `cmake .. && make install` "No rule to make target install"?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, installation

I was trying to use `cmake` to install some libraries and executables that are built via `cmake`.

I found [What is cmake equivalent of 'configure --prefix=DIR && make all install '?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003374/52074) which seemed to be easy. It looked like you just need to set the `cmake` variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and then `make install` should work.

I found that setting the `cmake` variable alone did not fix `make install` and I kept getting the error message "No rule to make target install".

**How do you fix `cmake .. && make install` "No rule to make target install"?**

p.s. `cmake` version is 2.8.x

Comment: Are you sure "install" is a valid target defined by that project?

Comment: @JesperJuhl see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047947/52074)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I consulted the Cmake textbook I have (or if you go to [the `cmake` tutorial0(https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/)). According to the textbook, in addition to setting the `cmake` variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` you also need to invoke the `cmake` function `install()` for anything you wish to be installed via the generated `Makefile`.

So in my case I set the variable in my CMakeLists.txt via:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX path/to/directory)
```

then under each `add_library()` and `add_executable()` I added:

```
install(TARGETS name1
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
    )
```

Then when I did `cmake .. && make && make install` I was successful and the expected files were installed at the expected destination.

Comment: This is not really a generic solution. Might have worked in your case, but in general there are different ways to set up a CMake project. The readme or some kind of documentation should tell you how to use it, if it's not obvious.

Comment: @super i guess this is not so generic. feel free to edit my solution. the point of my solution is that you have to have at least one `install()` function call in your `cmake` project. So my solution attempts to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the `cmake` function API usage for `install()`.

Comment: take a look at [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) built-in module also..
Then define config.cmake file also...

Comment: This answer helps a lot. Thank you, soldier! Too much gung ho for a **generic solution** that fails to spark a learning **aha** moment is pure evil. I believe in the strive for a **generic solution** in certain domains, but given the context that software build systems is an infant piece of engineering, it is better to expose the primitives necessary for new constructions.

Comment: @eigenfield thank you for understanding the reason i wrote this up (i.e. get something going that is easy to understand). the kind words are a nice counter balance to the criticisms of 'your solution is not generic'. i think the idea of "strive for generic solution" is a good idea... which is what i do in most of my code (because building robust generic solutions are 2-10x more lines and can be 2-10x harder to understand and can take 2x-10x more time to develop... and more importantly... most code does not need robust generic solutions).