# What is the meson equivalent of CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX?

Tags: installation, meson-build, buildconfiguration

I'm using to building code with CMake; but I'm now faced with using meson to build a certain repository. With `CMake` and `make`, if I use something like:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/some/where` build_dir
make -C build_dir
make -C build_dir install
```

then instead of the files going under `/usr/local` by default, they will go under `/some/where`, e.g. `/some/where/bin` for executables, `/some/where/lib`, for libraries etc.

What's the meson equivalent of doing this?

<sub>Inspired by:
 [What is CMake equivalent of 'configure --prefix=DIR && make all install '?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6003374/1593077)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually similar to the autotools convention in terms of the switch:

```
meson setup --prefix=/path/of/installation/destination build_dir
ninja -C build_dir
ninja -C build_dir install
```

(you could drop the first ninja command; `ninja install` will build before it installs.)