# error while trying to link spdlog static lib with cmake

Tags: cmake, spdlog

I installed spdlog static lib using there [doc](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog#static-lib-version-recommended---much-faster-compile-times) and try to link it to my program using there [example](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.x/example/CMakeLists.txt)
the installation path is this:
`/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/lib/external`

this is my CMAKE:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(test_1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost 1.75.0 COMPONENTS date_time system thread CONFIG)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    message("Boost found ${Boost_VERSION}")
    message("${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
endif()
find_library(CONNECTION
        NAMES connlib
        )
if(NOT CONNECTION)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CONNECTION library not found")
else()
    message("CONNECTION library found")
endif()

if(NOT TARGET spdlog)
    # Stand-alone build
    find_package(spdlog REQUIRED)
endif()


find_package(Threads)

add_executable(test_1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_1 PRIVATE ${CONNECTION} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} Threads::Threads pq spdlog::spdlog)
```

but Im getting this error:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package):   By not providing
> "Findspdlog.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked CMake
> to find a package configuration file provided by "spdlog", but   CMake
> did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "spdlog"
> with any   of the following names:
>
> ```
> spdlogConfig.cmake
> spdlog-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "spdlog" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "spdlog_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
> "spdlog"   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
> has been   installed.

so I added the `spdlog_DIR`
`set(spdlog_DIR ../lib/external/spdlog`
`find_package(spdlog PATHS ${spdlog_DIR } REQUIRED)`
with this error:

```
include could not find load file:

    /home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/lib/external/spdlog/build/spdlogConfigTargets.cmake
```

Comment: Does `/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/lib/external/spdlog/build/spdlogConfigTargets.cmake` exist?

Comment: @StephenNewell no, it farther down `/home/yaodav/Desktop/dnr_main_repo/lib/external/spdlog/build/CMakeFiles/Export/lib64/cmake/spdlog/spdlogConfigTargets.cmake` but when Im changing the spdlog_DIR to ther it telling me that i need the path to `spdlogConfig.cmake`

Comment: "I installed spdlog static lib using there doc" - Funny, but [Install section](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog#install) does NOT **install** `spdlog`, it just **builds** it. For **installing** you need to additionally run `make install`. Make sure that you choose appropriate install prefix (`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when running `cmake`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev do i have to install it if i want to use it?

Comment: In their [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.x/CMakeLists.txt) I see no `export()` call, so without installing the package you cannot use `find_package` for locate it. Note, that "installing" doesn't mean "installing into the system directory". As I said above, by using `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` you could choose the directory where the package will be installed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev like this `make install --prefix=CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` ?

Comment: No, it is like `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/install/dir ..` + `make install`. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003374/what-is-cmake-equivalent-of-configure-prefix-dir-make-all-install) about setting installation directory in CMake.

Comment: Did you try using `ExternalProject` or `FetchContent`, too?
Here's the description: https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/9.-CMake#use-as-static-library-with-externalproject_add-as-git-submodule
I use
```FetchContent_Declare(
 spdlog
 GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git
 GIT_TAG v1.9.2
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(spdlog)```
and you may add the options from the wiki back in if you like.

Comment: The advantage of `ExternalProject` or `FetchContent` is, that you don't need a separate install step.

Answer (score 3):

I found using FetchContent with spdlog was also the easiest. Just added these lines to my project:

```
...
Include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    spdlog
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/gabime/spdlog.git
    GIT_TAG v1.9.2
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(spdlog)
add_executable(project main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(project PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `libspdlog-dev`.
No need to change CMake files. Similar problem [here](https://github.com/gerbera/gerbera/issues/610).